# Binding property "fromICAO" not found on "ViewModel" in collectionview

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to show data using a collection view in Xamarin but the Binding for the text in one of the labels cannot find the property in the viewmodel

my view:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="ItemsCollectionView"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding Plans}"
                                 SelectionMode="None">
                     <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                             <Frame HasShadow="True">
                                 <StackLayout>
                                     <Grid>
                                         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                             <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                                         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                             <ColumnDefinition/>
                                             <ColumnDefinition/>
                                         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                         <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                                             <Label Text="From:" 
                                                    FontSize="10"
                                                    TextColor="Black"></Label>
                                             <Label Text="{Binding fromICAO}" 
                                                    FontSize="24"
                                                    TextColor="Black"></Label>
                                             <Label Text="To:" 
                                                    FontSize="10"
                                                    TextColor="Black"></Label>
                                             <Label Text="{Binding toICAO}" 
                                                    FontSize="24"
                                                    TextColor="Black"></Label>
                                         </StackLayout>
                                         <StackLayout  Spacing="0"
                                                       Grid.Column="1">
                                             <Label Text="Distance:" 
                                                    FontSize="10"
                                                    TextColor="Black"></Label>
                                             <Label Text="{Binding distance}" 
                                                    FontSize="24"
                                                    TextColor="Black"></Label>
                                             <Label Text="Fuel used:" 
                                                    FontSize="10"
                                                    TextColor="Black"></Label>
                                             <Label Text="{Binding fuelUsed}" 
                                                    FontSize="24"
                                                    TextColor="Black"></Label>
                                         </StackLayout>
                                     </Grid>
                                 </StackLayout>
                             </Frame>
                         </DataTemplate>
                     </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                 </CollectionView>
```

my viewmodel:

```
public ObservableCollection<PlanToFirestoreModel> Plans { get; set; }
    
         public PlansViewModel() {
             firestoreService = DependencyService.Get<IFirestoreService>();
             auth = DependencyService.Get<IFirebaseAuthentication>();
             Plans = new ObservableCollection<PlanToFirestoreModel>();
    
             FillData();
         }
    
         public async void FillData()
         {
             var tempPlans = await firestoreService.GetFlightPlansByUid(auth.GetUserInfoAsync().Id);
             foreach (var plan in tempPlans)
             {
                 Plans.Add(plan);
             }
         }
```

and my Model itself:

```
public class PlanToFirestoreModel : BasePlanModel
     {
         public string fromICAO { get; set; }
         public string toICAO { get; set; }
         public string fromName { get; set; }
         public string toName { get; set; }
         public int id { get; set; }
         public string userId { get; set; }
         public string aircraft { get; set; }
         public string deptCountry { get; set; }
         public string arrCountry { get; set; }
         public double fuelUsed { get; set; }
         public string flightNumber { get; set; }
         public double distance { get; set; }
         public string altitude { get; set; }
         public string createdAt { get; set; }
         public double deptLon { get; set; }
         public double deptLat { get; set; }
         public double arrLon { get; set; }
         public double arrLat { get; set; }
     }
```

The XAML page can find the Plans ObservableCollection itself but not the properties that are supposed to be in the list like "fromICAO" and "toICAO"
The label within the datatemplate can also only find Plans but not the properties within.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: All of your updates are happening on a separate thread to the UI thread and the UI thread is unaware of the updated data.

Comment: alright, is there a way I can gain access to this thread? or make a call to this thread?

Comment: at the top of your question you imply that only one Label/Property is broken, but at the end you imply that none of them work.  Which is it?

Comment: my IDE (visual studio) gives me 1 broken label in the error list but when looking at the code all of them seem to not find a binding so I think all of them.

Comment: have you verified that `Plans` actually contains data and that these properties are populated for each object?

Comment: @Jason Yeah it is filled: [link](https://imgur.com/a/EFGFvUX), it also renders 3 items which is the supposed amount, yet I still cannot call the individual properties

Comment: I should add that the 3 rendered items are blank and just hold placeholder text.

Comment: I don't see a `fromICAO` property on that object?  You can use Essentials MainThread to force the data to update on the UI thread, although that doesn't seem like the root issue to me

Comment: That fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using [Essentials Mainthread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/main-thread) to force data to update it worked and I could address the properties.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).